# Shortcut to swap characters in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'd like to be able to use `CTRL+T` as a shortcut for swapping/transpose 2 letters just like in Sublime Text, Netbeans and even Bash. Is it possible?

Couldn't find anything relevant on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple. Just create macros and then assign hotkey for this action. You can  watch full how-to video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5E1ETYOzelU

**UPD** Also i find this plugin  http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=phpStorm

**Swap Characters** - set a shortcut in Settings

Comment: Yes, I've created a macro that cuts the left-hand character, moves the cursor to the right and pastes the contents already but it has the disadvantage that it changes the contents of the clipboard. Any other ideas?

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=phpStorm i find this plugin. `Swap Characters - set a shortcut in Settings | Keymap` try it =)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! When I'll have some time I'll try to strip it down to only this function :D

Comment: Edit your answer and post this as an alternative and I'll accept it.